# Determining min and max x and y from a list of points

Tags: haskell

I'm still very new to this language so I'm having a tough time figuring out the best way to solve my problem.  I want to take a list of `Point`s such as `[(1,0),(2,3),(4,6)]` and determine the min and max `x` and `y` values, as I need to build a grid with them.

Here is my code:

```
type Point a = (a,a)

-- The main program: read points from stdin, write an SVG file to stdout. 
main :: IO ()
main = do
  str <- getContents
  let points = toPoints str
  let minXY = [(x,y) | x <- points, y <- points, x1 <- points, y1 <- points, x < x1, y < y1]
  mapM_ (mapM_ print) minXY
```

Comment: This question has been open for a while. If there is an answer that satisfies your question, please accept it by clicking the green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partition the list of points into lists of `x` and `y` coordinates using the `unzip` function, which converts a list of pairs into a pair of lists:

```
unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
points = [(1,0),(2,3),(4,6)]
unzip points = ([1,2,4],[0,3,6])
```

Then you can calculate the minimum and maximum of each of these lists straightforwardly with the `minimum` and `maximum` functions:

```
bounds :: [Point Int] -> ((Int, Int), (Int, Int))
bounds points = ((minimum xs, maximum xs), (minimum ys, maximum ys))
  where (xs, ys) = unzip points
```

---

Just for fun, here’s a more advanced solution that makes only a single pass over the coordinates:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Semigroup

bounds = unzip >>> minmax *** minmax
  where minmax = foldMap (Min &&& Max) >>> getMin *** getMax
```

It uses a few handy operators from `Control.Arrow`:

```
-- Apply two functions to a single value, returning both results.
(f &&& g) x = (f x, g x)

-- Apply two functions to the elements of a pair.
(f *** g) (x, y) = (f x, g y)

-- Left-to-right function composition.
(f >>> g) x = g (f x)
```

As well as the `Min` and `Max` monoids from `Data.Semigroup`:

```
getMin (Min 1 <> Min 2) == 1
getMax (Max 1 <> Max 2) == 2

getMin (foldMap Min [1, 3, 5]) == 1
getMax (foldMap Max [1, 3, 5]) == 5

getMin *** getMax $ foldMap (Min &&& Max) [1, 3, 5]
==
(1, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minimum` and `maximum` from prelude which compute the minimum and maximum of a list of numbers. Before calling those we need to map the list of tuples into a list of numbers using fst which gets the first item of a tuple or snd which gets the second item of a tuple.

To get the maximum of `x`

```
maximum $ fst <$> [(1,0),(2,3),(4,6)]
```

Same thing for minimum, for `y` use `snd` instead of `fst`

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to how the function you've described works?

Comment: Added more details

Answer (score 1):

@gabesoft solution is one way of doing it. The following will calculate the min and max in a single pass per axis.
Let's define a function that takes a tuple of a that represents the current result (accumulator or min and max values), a value of a, and returns the new result as a tuple.

```
minMax :: (Ord a) => (a, a) -> a -> (a, a)
minMax (minAcc, maxAcc) val = (min minAcc val, max maxAcc val)
```

We can now use this function in a fold:

```
points = [(1,2), (3, 4), (-1, -3)] :: [(Int, Int)]
foldl minMax (maxBound, minBound) points
```

We use maxBound/minBound to get the smallest/largest bounds for Int as a starting value.
However, that doesn't work on a list of tuples. To make it work on tuples you could do the following:

```
foldl minMax (maxBound::Int, minBound::Int) $ fst <$> points
foldl minMax (maxBound::Int, minBound::Int) $ snd <$> points
```

The `<$>` operator is `fmap`. So we first run `fst` over points to extract the first tuple values and apply the `minMax` function over this using a fold.